# Most efficient way to store and retrieve sockets in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

Currently I am storing the actual socket object in an array in each process.  I then store socket data in redis for all processes (workers) to access.

Is there a more performance/efficient way to store and retrieve sockets, or is this pretty much how this is done? I am concerned about performance when the sockets array potentially grows to over 200k objects.

```
var _ = require('underscore');

//Storing the socket in memory and saving the redis associated data
var server = this;
//This function adds this hash to redis and returns a unique id
server.gs.addSocketInfo({
     "userid": 0,
     "displayName": "Mike's iPhone",
     "connecttime": new Date().getTime()
  }, function(err, socketid) {
     socket.socketid = socketid;
     server.sockets.push(socket);
     doReady();
  });

//To retrieve the data and socket later
//function returns the socket data from redis
server.gs.getSocketInfo(socket.socketid, function(err, sinfo) {
    var socket = _.find(server.sockets, function(socket) {
       return socket.socketid === sinfo.socketid;   
    });
    if (socket)
       //Do something with the socket here...
});
```

Comment: The architecture of your solution is not clear from the question. Why are you putting socket data into Redis?

Comment: Some data about the socket such as the userid needs to be in redis for inter-process communication (using cluster).  I obviously didn't add all of the code for the example.  Is there anything I could add to make it more clear?

Comment: The fact that you're using a cluster is important. Are these regular old TCP sockets? or something higher level (ex: HTTP)? Are all of the processes in your system under your control, or are some of the systems clients which you don't control?

Comment: Actually I probably should mention this.  I have a net server and a http server using socket.io.  The socket objects in that array could be either an http socket or a tcp socket depending on what server was connected to.  All systems are under my control.  PS:  I made a change to the underscore retrieve.